# php fgetcsv and Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data

Tags: php, apache, fgetcsv

i have the following code, just for debug purpose:

```
 <?php
    if ($_FILES['productsFile']) {
    ini_set("display_errors","on");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('max_input_time ', 600000);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '180');
    ini_set('post_max_size ', "250M");
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize ', "250M");
    setlocale( LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' );
    $fileName = "ecom_productImport_".time();
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productsFile']['tmp_name'], "myfoter/".$fileName) upload");

    $handle = fopen($fileName, "r");

    $start=0;
    unset($fileName);
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 950000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      // some code that use insert and update queries
    }
}
```

now when i run this code on a command line - it runs without a problem but when i run it from a webpage in get the Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

any variable that is setted inside the loop is unsetted and the sql queries does not take long. i really have no clue about why it's keeping hanging up.

my webserver is apache 2 and the php version is 5.3.8

Comment: I see a trailing " at line 11

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productsFile']['tmp_name'], "myfoter/".$fileName) upload");` this is definitely not valid php code.

Comment: replace the move_uploaded_file with `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productsFile']['tmp_name'], "myfoter/".$fileName);`

Comment: You cannot change `post_max_size` or `upload_max_filesize` from within PHP code. PHP will have already aborted the upload when your `ini_set()` statement runs. Additionally, a memory limit of 512 MB is quite a lot. In my experience, PHP can't always handle that. Not sure why you need that if you appear to read the file in 950,000 byte chunks.

Comment: the move_uploaded_file works fine.

Alvaro - it might be possible that the 950,000 is too small?

Comment: Why do you ask that? Do you really want your script to require 512MB of RAM?